# Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, suspend, dpkg

Please help me this is a problem

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb libdir/

and then:

sudo cp libdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
sudo apt-get install -f

Taken from [old Ubuntu forum archives](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1266104.html).